# php : scan dir and save into txt with filter option

Tags: php

I have php funcation that scan dir and save content list into text.It works well but now i want to add filter funcation that restrict given extentoin to prevent to save into text.

```
function dirscan($dir,$file){
$folder = scandir($dir);
natsort($folder);
foreach ($folder as $value)
{
{
if ($value != '.' && $value != '..')
$val=$value."\r\n";
}
$fh = fopen($file,'a');
fwrite($fh,$val);
}
}
```

Comment: in your `if` on dots use either `pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) !== 'txt'` for singular or `!in_array(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), ['jpg','png','doc','etc']))` for multi

Comment: Might also look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function dirscan($dir,$file,$ext){
$folder = scandir($dir);
natsort($folder);
foreach ($folder as $value)
{
{
if ($value != '.' && $value != '..'&& pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) !== $ext)
$val=$value."\r\n";
}
$fh = fopen($file,'a');
fwrite($fh,$val);
}
}

$file_temp='list.txt';
unlink($file_temp);
```

credit for hint :Lawrence Cherone